# Selenium hangs after executing jscript command

Tags: java, selenium, freeze, jscript

I'm trying to click in a dynamic menu executing the following method:

```
public void clicaItemSubMenu(String item) throws InterruptedException{
    String link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + item + "')]")).getAttribute("Id");
    driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('" + link + "').click()");
}
```

The code works just fine and the menu is being opened and after that, `Selenium` hangs for FireFox or Internet Explorer. The issue does not happen if I debug the code. I've tried to deal with some wait stuff but, no success. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('" + link + "').click()");
Do you want to navigate to any page? Then, why click() at the end?

Comment: This line will click on the menu item that I need. I tried the default click() methods but those don't worked for these particular case. Now, the execution freezes every time at this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually [`WebDriver::get()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get-java.lang.String-) is used to load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using an `HTTP` `GET` operation, and the method will block until the load is complete while you want to perform click on element using `JavaScript`.

You should try using [`JavascriptExecutor::executeScript()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) which executes `JavaScript` in the context of the currently selected frame or window as below :-

```
public void clicaItemSubMenu(String item) throws InterruptedException{
  WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + item + "')]"));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", link);
 }
```

**Note** :- You can directly click on `WebElement` using [`WebElement::click()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click--) method as `link.click()` without using `JavascriptExecutor`.

Comment: Wow! this worked just fine! The link.click() will work for most of the cases but not for this one. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Ops, sorry, just marked as corrected. Im prety new to stack :)